# Why do people design EJB2 which is difficult to write and deploy?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-2.x

Many J2EE developers know that EJB2 forces them to write 'useless' Home interfaces. In addition, deployment XML are different among application servers.

So I don't know why EJB2 is part of J2EE specification for many years? Any non-technical interest are concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of EJB2 needs more programmer human resource. So EJB2 is good for programmer employment rate. This is a reason for EJB2 survive:)

Comment: By the way I do write EJB 2.1 code every day and the reason is that our customer would have to spend a huge amount of money to upgrade their weblogic licences to the higher version than 8 :). Sad but true.

Answer (score 8):

Are you asking why in general people still use EJB2.1?

Because:

- That's what they know, and they're frightened or don't have time for a new skill set.
- Because whoever wants that code wants it to follow a standard, and EJB2.1 is that standard.
- Because the rest of the code base is EJB2.1, and nobody has the time and/or money to refactor.
- Because the client only wants technology they trust, and what they trust is whatever hasn't failed them yet.

The same reasons anybody uses legacy technology, basically.

Answer (score 3):

Why EJB2 is part of the J2EE specs: because it is!
It once was, and so it will always be. (You cannot change a binding contract in mid-term.)

In order to *not* make it part of the specs, they had to come with new specs: Java EE
This is the updated version of J2EE, using Java 5.

Why it is still being used:

- see above
- the client has no money/time to change this
- the client uses and old version of the application server
- it works, so we do not change it